# GUI freezes when using async/await

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the code below. I thought that using async and await lets me forget about GUI issues such as freezing because some long code is blocking the main thread.

After I click the button, the GUI is responsive until the call to `longRunningMethod`, as shown below:

```
 private async void openButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    //doing some usual stuff before calling downloadFiles
    Task<int> result = await longRunningMethod(); // async method

    //at this point GUI becomes unresponsive

    //I'm using the result here, so I can't proceed until the longRunningMethod finishes

  }
```

I can't proceed until the method finishes, because I need the `result`. Why this code freezes my app?

Comment: the inside of  `longRunningMethod()`  is probably blocking the UI thread by not using `async/await` properly

Comment: If the `longRunningMethod` does not create a own thread, it will simply run in the UI thread and lock it.

Comment: @Adwaenyth That's not true at all. IO bound operations do not require a new thread to stop blocking the UI.

Comment: I noticed you are not returning Task<int>.  Does longRunningMethod start a new task?

Comment: @mrsargent yeah, sorry, I am returning Task<int> (modified the code a bit to simplify it)

Comment: @DanielKelley guess it is not an IO bound operation running in the method then.

Comment: try to use .ConfigureAwait(false) on your async method.  Check out this great article http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @user4205580 can you give some details about what's inside `longRunningMethod()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is within `longRunningMethod`.

What the code is *probably* doing is some CPU-bound or blocking operation.

If you want to run some CPU-bound code on a background thread, you have to do so explicitly; `async` won't jump threads automatically:

```
int result = await Task.Run(() => longRunningMethod());
```

Note that if `longRunningMethod` is CPU-bound, it should have a synchronous - not asynchronous - signature.

If `longRunningMethod` is *not* CPU-bound (i.e., it's currently blocking), then you need to change the blocking method calls within `longRunningMethod` to be asynchronous, and call them via `await`. Then you can make `longRunningMethod` asynchronous and call it via `await` as well:

```
int result = await longRunningMethodAsync();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it - GUI has an async method called when you press a button. When I call `await longRunningMethod`, it means no code in button's method will be executed until `longRunningMethod` completes. And for that time, the execution goes back to the method that called `openButton_Click` method. Executing an async method `longRunningMethod` should create a separate thread, right? That's the idea of async and await, as I said.

Comment: What are CPU-bound and blocking operations? I thought the first one was when an operation is using 100% of CPU power, and the second one is when some resource is waited for. But I didn't think that could cause any issues, like GUI freezing (I thought multiple threads can also run at the same time in such cases)

Comment: @user4205580: No, executing an async method does not create a separate thread. I have an [`async`/`await` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Ignoring the details, I'd say that async/await is an imitation of mutlithreading. The lines of two different pieces of code are executed in turns, on a single thread. If one of these lines will take long to run, no other lines will be executed until it finishes. Am I right?

Comment: @user4205580: Sort of. This is correct for async used on the UI thread, but not correct for any other scenario (ASP.NET, async on the thread pool, Console apps, etc).

Comment: What I meant was: http://pastebin.com/drzBVTec
This code runs on a single thread (I say one thread, because the number of threads that exited, as stated in VS console, is the same as in the case of a simple hello world). First, "Async 1" lines are printed, then `await Task.Delay` caueses a 1 ms pause in the async method, and as the pause has to be yet executed, control returns to main. The "Program..." and "Async 2..." lines printed in the console will interleave, so we have two methods running at the same time, on a single thread (imiation of multithreading).

Comment: @user4205580: Asynchrony is a form of *concurrency*, but it's not always on a single thread. In your pastebin, the async method resumes on a different thread.