# client.GetStreamAsync(url) is freezing my UI

Tags: c#, wpf

So I'm listening to an Server side event with my code to just write it on the console (for now) but it seems that this is making my window's form UI freeze

The code in question (which I'm calling from the main form's function)

```
static async Task hello()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Establishing connection");
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(await client.GetStreamAsync(url)))
                {
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var message = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Here you can check for 
                //specific types of errors before continuing
                //Since this is a simple example, i'm always going to retry
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine("Retrying in 5 seconds");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: most of my code comes from this tutorial https://makolyte.com/event-driven-dotnet-how-to-consume-an-sse-endpoint-with-httpclient/

Comment: When you reach EndOfStream you should exit the outside while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem, it appears that async/await task freezes the GUI. To stop this from happening you need to use Task.Run(() => your_function()); when you call an async function

This question might be a possible duplicate of: [GUI freezes when using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671919/gui-freezes-when-using-async-await) ... so go there if you want to find a bit more knowledge about the subject